# How to Enable Gzip Compression for SVG Images on Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: gzip, google-cloud-storage

Checking my website with Google Pagespeed Insights, I get the following warning:

> Enable compression Compressing resources with gzip or deflate can
>   reduce the number of bytes sent over the network. Enable compression
>   for the following resources to reduce their transfer size by 2.9KiB
>   (56% reduction). Compressing
>   https://MY_BUCKET.storage.googleapis.com/logo.svg could save 561B (49%
>   reduction).

It seems Google Cloud Storage does not have gzip enabled for svg's?
How can I enable gzip compression also for svg file type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you have to manually compress the svg:

`gzip -9 -S 'z' *.svg`

and then upload it with the Content-Encoding:

`gsutil -h "Content-Encoding:gzip" -h "Content-Type:image/svg+xml" cp logo.svgz gs://MY_BUCKET/logo.svgz`

Source: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#content-encoding

**UPDATE:**

This combines the two above commands, as mentioned by @jterrace

```
gsutil -h "Content-Encoding:gzip" -h "Content-Type:image/svg+xml" cp -Z logo.svg gs://MY_BUCKET/logo.svg
```

Comment: You can also use the `-z` or -`Z` options to gsutil cp.